# MySQL: problem with SELECT SUM()

Tags: php, mysql

my query:

```
SELECT events.*, SUM(analyt_event_hits.ajax_hits) AS ajax_hits
FROM events
LEFT JOIN analyt_event_hits
ON events.event_id = analyt_event_hits.event_id
WHERE events.date >= '$d'
```

the problem:

> this is only returning one result,
>   when it should be returning many.

The query works fine if i remove `SUM(anal_event_hits.ajax_hits) AS ajax_hits`

I'm a bit of a MySQL novice so hopefully i'm missing something obvious!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding

```
GROUP BY events.event_id
```

to the end.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a group function like `SUM` in a statement containing no GROUP BY clause, **it is equivalent to grouping on all rows**.

and  That's why you get only one row in results

More details on Aggregate Functions :

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html